# plt.legend only adds first element to scatter plot

Tags: python-3.x, scatter-plot, legend-properties

I am trying to add a legend to my scatter plot with 13 classes, however, with my code below, I am only able to get the first label.  Can you assist me in generating the full list to show up in the legend of the scatter plot?

Here is my example code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas import DataFrame
# generate 2d classification dataset
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, centers=13, n_features=2)

classes = [f"class {i}" for i in range(13)]

#fig = plt.figure()
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12))
scatter = plt.scatter(
    x=X[:,0],
    y=X[:,1],
    s = 20, 
    c = y, 
    cmap='Spectral'
    #c=[sns.color_palette()[x] for x in y_train_new]
    )
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.legend(classes)
plt.title('Dataset', fontsize=24)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by replacing the `plt.legend(classes)` in your code by this line... I hope this is what you are looking for. I am using matplotlib 3.3.4.

```
plt.legend(handles=scatter.legend_elements()[0], labels=classes)
```

**Output plot**

[image]